# Job control in dash

Tags: job-control, dash

I don't understand the problem about which the standard shell in Debian (dash) complains:

```
test@debian:~$ sh
$ man ls
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

```
[1] + Stopped                    man ls
$ jobs
[1] + Stopped                    man ls
$ fg %man
sh: 3: fg: %man: ambiguous
```

Shouldn't `fg %string` simply bring the job whose command begins with `string` to the foreground? Why is `%man` ambiguous?

Comment: without referring to the source, I suspect dash is expecting numeric job IDs, and so is failing in some way to translate "man" to a number.

Comment: Also, aside from this bug you've found....dash is a minimal posix sh, intended mainly for scripting rather than interactive use (it's fast because it doesn't carry around all the bloat/baggage that bash etc do).  IMO, it's best to use something else (bash, ksh, or zsh, for example) as your interactive command-line shell.   BTW, `bash` is still an `Essential: yes` package (at least on amd64 and i386, if not other arches), so will be installed on all Debian systems.

Comment: @cas: I normally use bash. For learning purposes I wanted to have a shell installed that comes close to the FreeBSD `sh` which is very minimal. What would be another option besides dash?

Comment: even on freebsd you don't have to use their minimal sh as your interactive shell.  install and use bash, but still write your scripts for portability using `#!/bin/sh` and only use shell features supported by sh.

Comment: @cas: Yes, of course, but I never claimed that one cannot use bash on FreeBSD. The FreeBSD sh was just an example for the kind of shell which I want.

Comment: so why ask me for minimal sh recommendations if you already know what you want?  my answer is "don't do that.  use bash"....as should have been obvious from my very first comment.

Comment: @cas: Just because I know what I want, doesn't mean I know how to get it. Dash has bugs. And FreeBSD sh doesn't exist on Linux.

Comment: i refer you to my previous comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a bug; the [loop which handles strings](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/jobs.c#n717) in this context doesn't have a valid exit condition:

```
        while (1) {
                if (!jp)
                        goto err;
                if (match(jp->ps[0].cmd, p)) {
                        if (found)
                                goto err;
                        found = jp;
                        err_msg = "%s: ambiguous";
                }
                jp = jp->prev_job;
        }
```

If a job matches the string, `found` is set, and `err_msg` is pre-loaded; then it goes round the loop again, after setting `jp` to the previous job. When it reaches the end, the first condition matches, so control goes to `err`, which prints the error:

```
err:
        sh_error(err_msg, name);
```

I guess there should be a `goto gotit` somewhere...

The following patch fixes this (I've sent it to the upstream maintainer):

```
diff --git a/src/jobs.c b/src/jobs.c
index c2c2332..37f3b41 100644
--- a/src/jobs.c
+++ b/src/jobs.c
@@ -715,8 +715,14 @@ check:

        found = 0;
        while (1) {
-               if (!jp)
-                       goto err;
+               if (!jp) {
+                       if (found) {
+                               jp = found;
+                               goto gotit;
+                       } else {
+                               goto err;
+                       }
+               }
                if (match(jp->ps[0].cmd, p)) {
                        if (found)
                                goto err;
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the dash version of fg have some bug or limitation to bring up the process when using a string instead of the job number.

What you can do is to use the number instead of the process name, like that:

```
fg %1
```

Im very sorry to say that!

In bash it works fine with the name, remember that fg is a shell built-in for the two shells, so fg of bash is not exactly the same command in dash and can have different bugs or limitation.